# ddply: Error with .drop argument

Tags: r, plyr

When I try this:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(2,3,1,2,3), b = factor(c('a','a','b','b','a'), levels = c('a','b','c')))

ddply(df, 'b', summarise, sum(a), .drop = F)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: upper value must be greater than lower value
```

Any idea why this happens? I tried several ways and none worked. Is this a bug of plyr?

Comment: It seems like you have `dplyr` attached. Detach `dplyr` and it works. Please note the warnings that are produced when you load both `plyr` and `dplyr`

Comment: You were right Henrik. Thanks a lot.

Comment: was hard for me to predict that behavior with this warning    Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:plyr’:

    arrange, desc, failwith, id, mutate, summarise, summarize

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.1.1. Would be nice if this behavior could be avoided.

Comment: If you load `plyr` after `dplyr` you receive the following message: "You have loaded plyr after dplyr - this is likely to cause problems. If you need functions from both plyr and dplyr, please load plyr first, then dplyr:library(plyr); library(dplyr)". In addition, if you have two or more packages with a function with the same name, you may explicitly pick the function from a certain package using the `::` function, e.g. `plyr::summarize`. See `"::"`.

Comment: "::" is really usefull. Thanks, Henrik.